# How can I use the results of this promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to build a `buildQuery` function for my social post feed:

```
const buildQuery = (criteria) => {
  const { userId, interest } = criteria;
  const query = {};

  if (interest !== 'everything') {
    if (interest === 'myInterests') {
      User.findById(userId).then(user => {
        return query.categories = {
         $in: user.interests
       };
      });
    } else {
      query.categories = { $eq: interest };
    }
  }
  return query;
};
```

If `interest` comes through as `myInterests` then I want to go find the array of `interests` belonging to the user (`userId`).

Each post has an array of categories: `query.categories`.

Once I get back the `interests` array, I want to look up `query.categories`, to filter down to the posts that the user is interested in `myInterests`.

Right now, my test is showing that this is just being ignored. It's bringing back all the posts. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: User.findById is asynchronous. The function returns before the User.findById query is executed.
Try promises or callbacks.

Comment: It's console logging `user.interests` though if I put it in the then statement?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wait for the results, and for that your function needs to return another promise for the updated query.

```
function buildQuery({userId, interest}) {
  if (interest === 'everything')
    return Promise.resolve({});
  else
    return (interest === 'myInterests'
      ? User.findById(userId).then(user => ({$in: user.interests}))
      : Promise.resolve({$eq: interest})
    ).then(categories => ({categories}));
}
```

Then wait for this promise before executing the query:

```
buildQuery(criteria).then(runQuery).then(results => … )
```